# Server Sent Events and Event ID

Tags: php, html, server-sent-events

How do i read the SSE ID sent from a HTML5 page that re-connects to the stream using PHP?

I read somewhere that use can access it with: $_SERVER["LAST-EVENT-ID"]

But it doesn´t seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The variable should be `$_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"]`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
$_GET["lastEventId"];
```